# If parameter is null, pull results from table

Tags: sql, t-sql

This might be a stupid question, but I haven't found a way to word this to get an answer that suits what I'm trying to accomplish. I might just be having a stupid moment.

I have an input variable for a sproc; that input variable may be passed in as null.

If the value is null, I would like insert into a temp table a list of values from another table. Otherwise, I'd just like to insert into the temple table the value of the parameter.

What I'm trying to do is something like this

```
INSERT INTO @tempTable
SELECT (CASE WHEN @myVariable IS NULL 
             THEN (SELECT [myVariable] FROM myTable) 
             ELSE @myVariable END)
```

This won't work because that select statement pulls back a large number of results (and it's malformed), but that's the general idea. I basically want to have an optional parameter where the user can specify a specific ID, or get back ALL the IDs.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to go about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think this UNION will do

```
INSERT INTO @tempTable
SELECT @myVariable WHERE @myVariable IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT [myVariable] FROM myTable WHERE @myVariable IS NULL
```

Of course if it doesn't need to be one query - you can use simple IF logic

```
IF @myVariable IS NULL
   INSERT INTO @tempTable
   SELECT [myVariable] FROM myTable
ELSE
   INSERT INTO @tempTable
   SELECT @myVariable
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(@myVariable, myVariableColumn) 
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this query:

```
INSERT INTO @tempTable
SELECT CASE WHEN @myVariable IS NULL Then [myVariable] else @myVariable end FROM myTable
```